# IntegrationTests for NHibernate.MappingException: No persister for:

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, integration-testing

If I forgot to add mappings to a persister object, NHibernate will throw an exception when I'll run the application.

I want to write an integration tests, that test that all mappings are provided to NHibernate. what is the way you recommend to follow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [this article](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2008/10/20/how-test-your-mappings-the-ghostbuster.aspx) (*Ghostbusters!*), or if you're using fluent-nhibernate you might like its [persistence specification testing](http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Persistence_specification_testing).